# Efficient/Pythonic way to create lists from pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've a `dataframe` as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'code' : [1,   2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10],
    'Tag' :  ['A','B','C','D','B','C','D','A','D','C']
})

+------+-----+
| code | Tag |
+------+-----+
|   1  |  A  |
+------+-----+
|   2  |  B  |
+------+-----+
|   3  |  C  |
+------+-----+
|   4  |  D  |
+------+-----+
|   5  |  B  |
+------+-----+
|   6  |  C  |
+------+-----+
|   7  |  D  |
+------+-----+
|   8  |  A  |
+------+-----+
|   9  |  D  |
+------+-----+
|  10  |  C  |
+------+-----+
```

My objective is to create `code` lists based on the common items in the `Tag` column as below.

```
codes_A = [1,8]
codes_B = [2,5]
codes_C = [3,6,10]
codes_D = [4,7,9]
```

How I'm doing it right now is

```
codes_A = df[df['Tag'] == 'A']['code'].to_list()
codes_B = df[df['Tag'] == 'B']['code'].to_list()
codes_C = df[df['Tag'] == 'C']['code'].to_list()
codes_D = df[df['Tag'] == 'D']['code'].to_list()
```

This code does the job. But, as you can see this is very cumbersome and inefficient. I'm repeating the same code multiple times and also repeating when I want to create new lists.

is there a more efficient and `pythonic` way to do this in `pandas` or `numpy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create dictionary of list, becasue [variable names are not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables):

```
d = df.groupby('Tag')['code'].agg(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'A': [1, 8], 'B': [2, 5], 'C': [3, 6, 10], 'D': [4, 7, 9]}
```

Then for list lookup by keys in dict, but no assign to variable name:

```
print (d['A'])
[1, 8]
```

So practically it means in your code if use `codes_A` then it change to `d['A']`, similar for all variables.

---

But if really need it:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    globals()[f'code_{k}'] = v
    
print (code_A)
[1, 8]
```

Comment: I want to create separate `lists` to be used in my other codes

Comment: @Tommy - hmmm, it is posible by `globals`, but it is not pythonic way.

Comment: `globals` is a bad thing in a lot of language. A good explanation: https://youtu.be/UEuXQjPUwcw